# Android - trouble updating SQLite after success webrequest on return statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a function that uses `StringRequest` to send a post request to my server. The script on the server side updates the database with the user's new settings.

The server side script returns 1 on success and 0 on failure, with appropriate message too. What I have tried to do with the `StringRequest` function is a similar thing.

```
public int updateLiveSettings(Switch discoverySwitch, Switch menSwitch, Switch womenSwitch) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    final String email = db.getFromTable(getActivity(), "email", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_LOGIN, "WHERE _id="+uid);
    final String discovery = switchValue(discoverySwitch);
    final String men = switchValue(menSwitch);
    final String women = switchValue(womenSwitch);

    final String tag_string_req = "update_settings";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_UPDATE_SETTINGS, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        success = jObj.getInt("success");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (success == 1) {
                            Log.i(tag_string_req, success+" - yes");

                        } else {
                            // Error in login. Get the error message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", tag_string_req);
            params.put("account", discovery);
            params.put("men", men);
            params.put("women", women);
            params.put("email", email);
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    return success;
}
```

Success is always returned as either 1 or 0. I then use this to update the stored settings in the SQLite database.

```
womenSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // do something, the isChecked will be 
            //Log.i("live attempt", updateLiveSettings(discoverySwitch, menSwitch, womenSwitch)+"");
            if(updateLiveSettings(discoverySwitch, menSwitch, womenSwitch) == 1){
                Log.i("womenswitch", "live update success");
                if(isChecked==true){
                    Log.i("womenswitch", "is checked");
                    db.update(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "women=1", "uid="+uid);
                }else{
                    Log.i("wpmenswitch", "is not checked");
                    db.update(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "women=0", "uid="+uid);
                    if(menSwitch.isChecked()==false){
                        menSwitch.setChecked(true);
                        db.update(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "men=1", "uid="+uid);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    });
```

The problem I'm having is that even when the update is successful and the correct int is returned the local database isn't updated.

It basically never gets passed `if(updateLiveSettings(discoverySwitch, menSwitch, womenSwitch) == 1)` I get nothing in the LogCat so I can only assume I'm doing this incorrectly.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: When you get nothing in the logcat, add more `Log` statements. It will help you seeing what's going on, and it will help us in helping you.

Comment: When looking at the code, you should see at least either "Response:" or "Error:" in the logcat. Furthermore, where does `success` from `return success` come from? This shouldn't even compile, AFAICS.

Comment: @OlafDietsche sorry I should have been a bit more clear. By nothing in the LogCat i meant nothing when it comes to the Logs in the switch listener. I always get a "Response: " log and even the success+" - yes" but when it comes to the listener i get nothing regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nature of an asynchronous request.

When you look at the image at [Send a Request](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#send) (and at your code), you can see that the request is put into a request queue. Only when the request is performed or a result taken from the cache, it will return to your main thread in the form of the `onResponse` or `onErrorResponse` method.

But when the result is delivered to your application, your method `updateLiveSettings` has already returned and delivered whatever was in the `success` variable. You can see this order of events, when you add a `Log` output *after* the `if` statement.

To update the database based on the `success` result, you must do this inside the `onResponse` method, e.g.

```java
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // ...
    updateLiveSettings(discoverySwitch, menSwitch, womenSwitch, isChecked);
}
```

and in `updateLiveSettings()`

```java
public void onResponse(String response) {
    Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
    try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        int success = jObj.getInt("success");

        // Check for error node in json
        if (success == 1) {
            Log.i(tag_string_req, success+" - yes");

            if (isChecked==true){
                Log.i("womenswitch", "is checked");
                db.update(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "women=1", "uid="+uid);
            } else {
                Log.i("wpmenswitch", "is not checked");
                db.update(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "women=0", "uid="+uid);
            }
        } else {
        // ...
```